# Different environment variables when using Android

Tags: android, c++, android-emulator, android-source

I have modified some of the Android source code to create a socket for me during the time when init.rc is run. What happens is that the descriptor for the socket is created and saved in an environment variable. This is similar to how other sockets are created in init.rc(example being ANDROID_SOCKET_zygote). My problem is that I do not know how to get access to my env variable(named ANDROID_SOCKET_mySocket).

From the command line, I can type 'adb shell printenv' this will correctly print out my socket and another socket(ANDROID_SOCKET_adbd).

Now in the android source code, where I am trying to get access my socket descriptor(specifically in DisplayDevice.cpp). I call the getenv function to try to get my env variable and its not found. I even printed out all the env variables available to me in that file and the env var I was looking for was not found.

Does anyone know why this is the case. I can provide more information if needed.

Comment: Are you running as root in user land?

Comment: I am only running this on an emulator. I'm not sure exactly what you mean by this comment. There doesn't seem to be any permission issues here only an env variable issue.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I suspect that env vars created during init are only readable by root.  Have you tried using sudo?  try this:`adb shell` then `su` then `printenv`.  Do you see it then?

Comment: You may have misunderstood my intentions. I am correctly able to see it using adb shell printenv(without su). It is when I am inside of the code, that I am not able to find my env variables.

Comment: If you use socket in init.rc, it will only added to the environment variables of the target service. So I'm pretty curious about how you can get your socket from adb shell printenv. Did you add "socket ..." under the service adbd?